# Notification background image never shown on clock

Tags: android, wear-os

I don't get it manages to show the background I did that based on the ElizaChat example but I don't get the background it is always black.

Here is my code:

```
public static void createNotification(Context context) {
    int notificationId = 1;

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigStyle.bigText("I am a big style message");

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("hallo")
            .setContentText("I am a message")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.getResources(), R.drawable.clock_bg))
            //.setStyle(bigStyle)
            ;

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    Notification notification =
        new WearableNotifications.Builder(notificationBuilder)
            .setHintHideIcon(true)
            .setMinPriority() // show only on clock
            .build();

    // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

Any Idea?

This is my output:

[image: clock]

Comment: just a guess: there're other points where u can set an image. Maybe the Wear is getting from one of the others. `Builder.setLargeIcon`, `BigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon` and `BigPictureStyle.bigPicture` Maybe one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to use the `WearableExtender` like in this short example:

```
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), background);
extender.setBackground(bg);
notificationBuilder.extend(extender);
```

---

**Original Answer** */ alternative*

I found a solution I need to use the BigPictureStyle like this:

```
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                                 R.drawable.clock_bg);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("hallo")
                .setContentText("I am a message")
                .setLargeIcon(background)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                                .bigPicture(background));
```

Comment: any idea if you can set BigPictureStyle for the wearable notification and 'standard' style for the phone notification?

Comment: @Reustonium As I pointed out in the question part that setMinPriority call enforces that the notification is only shown on the clock. Possible there is another call which avoids that so you could simple create two different notifications. However maybe it is also possible to implement a custom Style which supports both, but I don't know that yet.